How to resolve possibly conflicting recursive Rust trait implementations?
With the following code, I am able to add functionality to existing types:
pub trait Action<RHS> {
    fn action(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self;
}

impl Action<i8> for u8 {
    fn action(self, _rhs: i8) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

This lets me do something like 1u8.action(1i8). I'd like to apply this to wrapped types as well so tried:
pub struct Pen<A>(pub A);

impl<A: Action<B>, B> Action<Pen<B>> for Pen<A> {
    fn action(self, rhs: Pen<B>) -> Self {
        Self(self.0.action(rhs.0))
    }
}

This lets me do Pen(1u8).action(Pen(1i8)), Pen(Pen(1u8)).action(Pen(Pen(1i8))), etc.
I also want it to work with the argument unwrapped, e.g. Pen(1u8).action(1i8):
impl<A: Action<B>, B> Action<B> for Pen<A> {
    fn action(self, rhs: B) -> Self {
        Self(self.0.action(rhs))
    }
}

This gives me a conflicting implementation error between the last two impls. I can see how the compiler can interpret B in the last impl to be a Pen but there don't seem to be actual conflicting types. The first impl deals with the same "pen-depth". The second impl deals the cases where the rhs is less deep. If I hard-code the implementations for specific concrete types, it works.
How do I achieve the flexibility of having action take both a wrapped and unwrapped parameter?

Playground

You cannot. It's simple.

@ChayimFriedman There is no ambiguity. Why not?

Because the language does not support this use case. It's impossible.

Then the error is wrong, claiming conflict when there is none.

There is a conflict. When checking Pen<i8>::action(Pen<i8>), both impls apply. What you want is a way to prefer one impl, or restrict one impl to not include Pens, and that is something Rust does not provide.

It is probably not a good idea, but you could try to use the unstable specialization feature.
